# GNU Screen: deleted directory screen was started in

Tags: gnu-screen

I started screen in a directory I since deleted and every time I open a new window I get the following error:

> shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
>   parent directories: No such file or directory sh: 0: getcwd() failed:
>   No such file or directory

Pretty understandable error! Is there a way to reset screen's default directory while it's running? I'd really rather not have to restart screen entirely, or recreate the deleted directory to appease screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command`C-a:chdir /path/to/new/dir` changes the working directory, and thus the directory that new windows open into.